# Have I found a bug in Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

The following command gives `0` in *Mathematica* 9.0.1.

```
f[a_, b_] := Exp[I*(a*x^3 + b*x^2)];
Integrate[f[a, b], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, Element[b,Reals]}]
```

This seems to be wrong, see the following article:
http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5031

Is this really a bug and if yes, is it known (is it perhaps even some instance of a bigger problem)?

Comment: I get the same, but a simple rescaling gives a sensible result : `int[p_, c_] = 
 p Integrate[Exp[I*( x^3 + c*x^2)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {c \[Element] Reals}]`. For instance, `int[1/a^(1/3), b/a^(2/3)] /. {a -> 1/3, b -> 1} // N` checks with the result in the link.

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag initially; it is meant to be added only once a consensus has been reached or a bug is recognized by WRI.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I didn't know that - Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Looks like a clear bug to me.

Comment: Have put in place a provisional fix. Now hoping nothing breaks as a result of that-- would be nice for the fix to survive until the next release.

Comment: @jVincent @vonjd This is because the `Element` symbol is typed wrong as $\epsilon$ in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you can work around this problem by using ExpToTrig to rewrite your expression.  That is, this produces a result that seems to check out:

```
f[a_, b_] := Exp[I*(a*x^3 + b*x^2)];
result = Integrate[ExpToTrig[f[a, b]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b  \[Element] Reals}]
```

Evaluating this returns:

```
(2 E^((2 I b^3)/(27 a^2)) \[Pi] Abs[b] (BesselJ[-(1/3), (2 Abs[b]^3)/(27 a^2)] + BesselJ[1/3, (2 Abs[b]^3)/(27 a^2)]))/(9 a)
```

Let's check the result at one spot in the parameter space:

```
result /. {a -> 21, b -> 1/3} // N

0.560793 + 3.48872*10^-6 I
```

This seems to check out:

```
NIntegrate[f[21, 1/3], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

0.560793 + 3.48872*10^-6 I
```

Given the above results, I think that is is pretty clear that the original result from Integrate (without TrigToExp) is not correct.

Comment: Moreover the complex exponential route has trouble in Slater convolution when it hits things like Exp[2*Log[I*a]], which it cannot discern from Exp[2*Log[-I*a]] (both show up because we integrate from -infinity to zero by negating and going 0 to infinity). An effort is made to unravel such things, but apparently this is not always getting it correct.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug to me because the zero result implies the integral is identically zero under the assumptions, but

```
With[{a = 1, b = 1}, Integrate[f[a, b], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

which clearly satisfies the assumptions, gives

> ```
> (2 E^((2 I)/27) \[Pi] AiryAi[-(1/(3 3^(1/3)))])/3^(1/3)
> ```

and has the numerical value of

> 1.79889 + 0.133495 I